# Symfony2 XPath returns duplicate nodes

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, xpath, nodes

I'm trying to excute some sql queries from a XML file but when I get the query from a tag, it returns the queries more times than expected.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<informes>
    <informe>
    </informe>
    <indicadores>
        <indicador>
            <sql>
                SELECT concat('Total Facturacion: ', round(sum(total))) as valor FROM infomatrix.dtmax_facturacion
            </sql>
            <link>

            </link>
        </indicador>
        <indicador>
           <sql>
                SELECT concat('Stock total: ', round(sum(cantidad))) as valor FROM infomatrix.dtmax_stock
           </sql>
           <link>

           </link>
        </indicador>
    </indicadores>
</informes>
```

This is my php code:

```
    $sqlIndicador = $crawler->filterXpath('informes/indicadores/indicador');
    $elements = array();
    foreach($sqlIndicador as $element){
        $elements[] = $element->getElementsByTagName("sql")->item(0)->nodeValue;
    }
    $indicadores = array();
    foreach ($elements as $indicador) {
        $data = $repositorio->obtenerSqlIndicador($indicador);
        array_push($indicadores,$data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the structure is the same between the nodes, the $sqlIndicador is returning 2 results, which you are iterating and getting 2 more.

Make your filter as 'informes/indicadores' and then you loop into it, which is going to be the 'indicador' element, 2 results in that case. And from this element you get the sql.

Comment: It didn'n work. It might return two queries but It returns four times every query instead.

Comment: Can you make a phpfiddle or something like that?